# Unity Firebase SDK Gives an DatabaseException when initilazing DatabaseReference

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I've installed Unity Firebase SDK, firebase google-services and configured Player Settings with com project name. After that, I've written the following lines of code:

```
private DatabaseReference _databaseReference;
    private string _userID;

    private void Start()
    {
        _databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        _userID = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
    }
```

Even though I followed the steps from the official documentation, I got an error:

> DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your GetInstance() call.
> Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance (Firebase.FirebaseApp app, System.String url)

Can someone help me please?

I've also tried adding `FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance()` but I get an error:

> DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your GetInstance() call.
> Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `Google-Service-info.plist` or `GoogleServices.json` file that you're using doesn't include the correct database URL.

So work around that, specify the URL of the database in your `GetInstance` call:

```
_databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance("your database URL here").RootReference;
```

You can find the URL in the Firebase console for your database.